# UK visa Application Q : Main purpose of travel ? And Travel Dates Question?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

This my parent second visiotor visa application [image]of 6 month. The first 6 month got approved in Dec 2018, now submitting another one, 
at that time my sister had medical degree graduation which was stated the main purpose of visit, 
[image]
Now there isnt such ceremony or need just a visitor visa to meet their daughter and her family in summer or when we feel our parents have time for 2 to 3 weeks,
Second it asks for dates of visit to uk so what should i put in the dates as the dates for travel as the dates are also not if sure ?

Comment: Surely the purpose is ‘tourism including visiting family and friends’ or similar?  As to the date of the visit, that’s up to you to decide providing the start date is within 3 months of the application date. Your parents can finalise the actual travel dates once the visa is approved, sticking more or less to the requested length of visit.

Comment: @WorldWillEnd I rather think David Richerby understood the question, what he didn’t understand was why you needed to ask it at all since you/your parents are the only ones who could possibly know the answer.

Comment: @WorkdWillEnd That Information is available here https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa therefore I almost didn’t include it in my answer. It is best to read the official guidance first before asking a question - TSE is a bunch of random strangers on the internet who have quite a lot of knowledge/experience between them but typically are not immigration experts in a professional sense

Comment: if your idea of "cautious" is "decide what lie to put on my application so it will work this time" I don't expect any of your applications to succeed

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate purpose is ‘tourism including visiting family and friends’ or similar.

As to the date of the visit, that’s up to you to decide providing the start date is within 3 months of the application date. Your parents can finalise the actual travel dates once the visa is approved, sticking more or less to the requested length of visit. UKVI specifically advise against pre-booking travel before you receive the decision; providing proof of flight/hotel reservations is not required when applying.